# What kind of monitor has Python?

Tags: python, concurrency

What kind of monitors (concurrent programming) has Python? Brinch Hansen, Hoare or Lampson / Redell (like Java)?

- Brinch Hansen: the notifier thread exits the monitor, and the notified continues.
- Hoare: the notifier thread enters in a special queue, and the notified continues.
- Lampson / Redell: the notifier thread continues, and the notified enters in the entry queue.

Comment: Yes, but the GIL only ensures that two threads aren't running at the same time. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered in the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects):

> The wait() method releases the lock, and then blocks until it is
>   awakened by a notify() or notifyAll() call for the same condition
>   variable in another thread. Once awakened, it re-acquires the lock and
>   returns. It is also possible to specify a timeout.
>
> The notify() method wakes up one of the threads waiting for the
>   condition variable, if any are waiting. The notifyAll() method wakes
>   up all threads waiting for the condition variable.
>
> **Note: the notify() and notifyAll() methods don’t release the lock**;
>   this means that **the thread or threads awakened will not return from
>   their wait() call immediately**, but only when the thread that called
>   notify() or notifyAll() finally relinquishes ownership of the lock.

Comment: So, it is Lampson / Redell

Answer (score 0):

According to the [J. Mongan's book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-interviews-exposed/9781118283400/), a Monitor is a set of routines that are protected by a mutual exclusion lock.

A example code may be more understandable, so I copied [a Doug Hellmann's code of synchronizing thread (canonical concurrency)](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/#synchronizing-threads). This snippet included `wait()` and `notifyAll()` functions:

```
    import logging
    import threading
    import time

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s (%(threadName)-2s) %(message)s',
                        )

    def consumer(cond):
        """wait for the condition and use the resource"""
        logging.debug('Starting consumer thread')
        t = threading.currentThread()
        with cond:
            cond.wait()
            logging.debug('Resource is available to consumer')

    def producer(cond):
        """set up the resource to be used by the consumer"""
        logging.debug('Starting producer thread')
        with cond:
            logging.debug('Making resource available')
            cond.notifyAll()

    condition = threading.Condition()
    c1 = threading.Thread(name='c1', target=consumer, args=(condition,))
    c2 = threading.Thread(name='c2', target=consumer, args=(condition,))
    p = threading.Thread(name='p', target=producer, args=(condition,))

    c1.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    c2.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    p.start()
```

When you run this code, the output would like this:

```
2021-11-22 15:49:56,672 (c1) Starting consumer thread
2021-11-22 15:49:58,675 (c2) Starting consumer thread
2021-11-22 15:50:00,678 (p ) Starting producer thread
2021-11-22 15:50:00,678 (p ) Making resource available
2021-11-22 15:50:00,678 (c1) Resource is available to consumer
2021-11-22 15:50:00,679 (c2) Resource is available to consumer
```